# How to correctly create a simple command line Spring application in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, ide

I have to start a simple Spring project (it is a batch file that perform a query on a database and then iterate on the obtained records).

I always created Spring project from Eclipse, now I have to do it from IntelliJ (the comunity edition).

I am trying to do **File --> New --> Project**, here I select **Maven** but I can't find archetype related to the structure of a simple Spring command line application. Why?

How can I create a simple Spring command line application in IntelliJ?

Comment: Try this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/enabling-spring-support.html

Answer (score 1):

1) **Add the Plugin** "Maven Archetype Catalogs" to Intelij

```
1.1) File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browse repositories...

1.2) Search for "Maven archetype" and look for the "Maven Archetype Catalogs"

1.3) Click on Install button of that plugin. After finished click the restart intelij button
```

2) **Create a New Project** on Intelij **based on Spring Boot Sample Simple Archetype**

```
2.1) File -> New -> Project

2.2) Check the option "Create from archetype" and click the Add Archetype button

2.3) Fill the window fields with the following information

    GroupId: org.springframework.boot
    ArtifactId: spring-boot-sample-simple-archetype
    Version: 1.0.2.RELEASE
    Repository: http://central.maven.org/maven2/

2.4) Click OK
```

This will tell the intelij to download the new archetype and create a new maven project
based on this archetype with sample source code using Spring Boot CommandLinner

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven archetypes from [Spring official archetype catalog](https://repo.spring.io/release/archetype-catalog.xml) for Spring Boot applications.

Press "Add Archetype..." button when create maven project:

[image]

Or choose Spring project type, like this:

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that you ar adding a "Spring Boot" archtype. I don't need Spring Boot but only a simple Spring application (it is something more like a batch application, not web related application). Why you are adding this archetype?

Comment: @AndreaNobili It's just fo example, you can find `spring-boot-sample-batch-archetype` in archetype catalog.

Comment: Yes, there is only Spring boot archetypes(

Comment: And if I want to build a simple Spring application what can I do?

Comment: @AndreaNobili I supplemented my answer.

Comment: I have not the "Spring" option in the type of project list (I only have Java, Java FX, Android, IntelliJPlatform Plugin, Maven, Gradle, Groovy, Grifon, Kotlin and Empty Project. Could depend by the fact that I am using the "Comunity Edition" and so it is not complete?

Comment: Yes it's only in Ultimate version

Comment: You don't need Ultimate to use Spring. Just create a normal empty maven project, add which Spring dependencies you want, and run it.

Comment: @AndreaNobili Spring Boot is not only about Web applications, but it also supports Command Line applications, please see the Spring CommandLinerRunner reference at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner  this means that you can use the spring-boot-sample-simple-archetype to build your command line application

Answer (score 0):

Create a Maven project, add [spring-context](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context) dependency, create @Configuration class and run it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
    MessagePrinter printer = context.getBean(MessagePrinter.class);
    printer.printMessage();
}
```

Full  tutorial: https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/